# Eclipse null analysis: The expression of type int needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@Nonnull Integer'

Tags: java, eclipse, null, static-analysis, non-nullable

When configuring Eclipse 4.2.0 to perform a null analysis (configured to use `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` etc.), the following code will generate the warning

> Null type safety: The expression of type int needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to '@Nonnull Integer'

```
class C
{
  static void foo(int i)
  {
    bar(i); // Warning
  }

  static void bar(@javax.annotation.Nonnull Integer i)
  {
  }
}
```

How am I supposed to fix this (without using `@SuppressWarnings("null")`)? It seems that the analyzer does not know that boxed primitives cannot be `null`.

Comment: This was a bug in Eclipse, which got fixed for milestone 7 of the upcoming 4.5 release.

Comment: Its not entirely fixed, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Eclipse. I tried the same with IntelliJ, and it works as expected there.

When I pass a Null, IntelliJ correctly tells me that nulls are not allowed.

[image]

However, when I use the normal i variable, no error pops ups up, which is quite correct.
[image]

I even tried this, just for the experiment, so I'm not sure if you're stuck to Eclipse, else I'd recommend using either the free [Community version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html) of IntelliJ, or the [Ultimate edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html).

[image]